# Flutter : space between with non-fixed width

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add spaceBetween property to a Row with Flutter. I want to keep my first container width null to resize itself.

Here is my code :

```
Container(
      width: null, // I want to keep the width null to resize itself
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, kIsWeb ? 20 : 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        color: secondaryBackground,
      ),
      child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // this doesn't work
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                color: textColor.withOpacity(.1),
              ),
              child: Text("First Item",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: textColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                color: textColor.withOpacity(.1),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Second Item",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: textColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ), [...]
```

[The result I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC6fu.png)

[The result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr1eq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `expanded` widget between both the widgets in Row.

Comment: When I try this, everything disappear and I get the following error : RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#85571 relayoutBoundary=up25
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: remove null from container.